Every time I open an icon it appears duplicated in my panel. Lubuntu 24.04
Here is my problem: The icons duplicate in the panel when I open them


I'd remove that "duplicate" tag, if I were you. This tag usually means "someone else already asked this question".

@TSJNachos117 hover over the tag and you will see that it is not as you suggest. The tag is valid.

Are the icons duplicate or are you opening multiple instances and you want them stacked?

Just duplicate in the panel in a single session. When I click on firefox,for instance, it appears two times in the panel, just as in the picture I uploaded

Hit Configure Panel (right click on suitable area of panel; not on widget) and go to Widgets tab, then ensure you've not applied a duplicate entry there; ie. if you add Task Manager when its already there; two displays of that widget occur (ie. items get listed for first widget, then for second that was added to panel).

Done! In configure,widgets, just deleted the showdesktop widget , that had the same icon than the desktopswitch. It was just trial and error, but following your advises I achieved what I wanted. Naturally I don´t have an explanation for that outcome, but, you surely do. Thanks a lot!

Hit Configure Panel (right click on suitable area of panel; not on a widget; if your mouse pointer is over a widget you'll get the menu for widget management, where you want to configure the panel; you'll see 'Configure Panel' option when in an appropriate area) and go to Widgets tab.

Ensure you've not applied a duplicate entry there; ie. if you add Task Manager when its already there; that widget will appear twice in your panel, meaning you'll see items for the first task manager widget, then it repeated again for the second task manager widget.
The appropriate page in the Lubuntu Manual is https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html which maybe helpful.
